# VBA: Userform Textbox_Change Only Works Once

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Having a weird issue with Excel Userforms.

I've got 2 userforms, one with a textbox and the other with a button. The one with the textbox uses Textbox_Change event to track what's in the box and after 10 characters have been entered it loads Userform2.

When Userform2 initialises Userform1 is unloaded. Userform2 has a button which then reloads Userform1.

This is a very slimmed down version of my end result, but I needed to see it in it's most basic form to make sure it wasn't my code that was causing an issue.

Anyway, when I'm typing in Userform1's text box it tracks the changes of TextBox1, but after it's reloaded it stops tracking.

Below is my code.

Userform1:

```
Dim Iteration As Integer
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Debug.Print Me.TextBox1.Value

    Iteration = Iteration + 1

    If Iteration = 10 Then

        UserForm2.Show

    End If

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Iteration = 0

End Sub
```

Userform2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

It's as simple as it could possibly be.

When I first loaded Userform1 I entered into the text box "1234567890", which outputted the console:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
```

As expected.

However after I've loaded Userform2 and then click the button to reload Userform1, when I enter "abcdefghij" into the textbox it doesn't output anything to the console.

Is there some fundamental concept of userforms that I'm missing here? Or something I'm getting wrong? I can't see anything that would be causing this.

I've been reading up on what unloading and show actually does and I can't find anything that'd affect whether or not the event should fire. From what I know when you run Userform.show it reinitialises everything, but even if it didn't it should still output SOMETHING to the console.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
even if I change Userform 1 to be:

```
Dim Iteration As Integer
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Debug.Print Me.TextBox1.Value

    Iteration = Iteration + 1

    If Iteration = 10 Then

        Unload Me
        UserForm1.Show

    End If

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Iteration = 0

End Sub
```

It still doesn't track changes on the second time round.

Comment: what would you use two forms in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed the issue.

I'm not sure why it works, need to look into it further, but if I add `vbModeless` to the `.show` function when initialising a userform it allows me to track changes on the second form.